# Why spi.recieve() function always return zero in SPI of mbed?

Tags: c++, spi, mbed

I want to set up a SPI connection between two mbed boards and I found that the spi.recieve() function which is used to detect the data transmission from the master always return zero and the connection can't be established.

I try to remove 'if' in my code, and it works, but I still don't understand why the function returns zero.

here is some code:

```
while (1)
  {
    transmit_value = 100 * voltage;
    spislave.reply(transmit_value);
    if (spislave.receive())
    {
      receive_value = spislave.read();
    }
```

here is my completed code:

```
#include <mbed.h>
Serial pc(USBTX, USBRX);
SPISlave spislave(p5, p6, p7, p8);
AnalogIn voltage(p20);
PwmOut led(p21);
BusOut display(p9, p10, p11, p12, p13, p14, p15, p16);
DigitalOut GroundLeft(p27);
DigitalOut GroundRight(p28);
int main()
{
  char transmit_value = 50;
  char receive_value = 60;
  spislave.format(8,0);
  spislave.frequency(1000000);
  while (1)
  {
    transmit_value = 100 * voltage;
    spislave.reply(transmit_value);
    if (!spislave.receive())
    {
      receive_value = spislave.read();
    }
    led.write(receive_value / 100.0);
    int leftnum = receive_value / 10;
    int rightnum = receive_value % 10;
    pc.printf("%d\n", receive_value);
    GroundLeft = 0;
    GroundRight = 1;
    switch (leftnum)
    {
    case 0:
      display = 0x3F;
      break;
    case 1:
      display = 0x06;
      break;
    case 2:
      display = 0x5B;
      break;
    case 3:
      display = 0x4F;
      break;
    case 4:
      display = 0x66;
      break;
    case 5:
      display = 0x6D;
      break;
    case 6:
      display = 0x7D;
      break;
    case 7:
      display = 0x07;
      break;
    case 8:
      display = 0x7F;
      break;
    case 9:
      display = 0x6F;
      break;
    }
    wait(0.01);
    GroundLeft = 1;
    GroundRight = 0;
    switch (rightnum)
    {
    case 0:
      display = 0x3F;
      break;
    case 1:
      display = 0x06;
      break;
    case 2:
      display = 0x5B;
      break;
    case 3:
      display = 0x4F;
      break;
    case 4:
      display = 0x66;
      break;
    case 5:
      display = 0x6D;
      break;
    case 6:
      display = 0x7D;
      break;
    case 7:
      display = 0x07;
      break;
    case 8:
      display = 0x7F;
      break;
    case 9:
      display = 0x6F;
      break;
    }
    wait(0.01);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you not following the reference code? https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.9/reference/spislave.html

With SPI you have to understand that RX and TX happen at the same time and that the operation will take some amount of time.

`.reply()` sets up what to send, `.receive()` checks if something has been received (which probably won't be immediately), and `.read()` gets data from SPI controller.

Comment: My code is modified from that example, and everything is right except the'.receive()' function. When I receive something from the master,  '.receive()' still return zero and I want to know why.

Comment: Start with the working example, keep adjusting towards your code until it breaks - you'll find a problem.

Comment: Your updated code has the same issue that I described. You're calling `receive` immediately after `reply`, so to me that makes sense that it fails. In mbed example when `receive` fail, loop will continue and retry it until it succeeds.